# Ajax UpdatePanel w/large Dropdown - lag-time when posting

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a page that uses an Ajax updatepanel to process one section of data without doing a full postback.  The panel contains about eight fields, including one dropdownlist that can get quite large (7500+ items).

When initially loading the form, populating the dropdown can add several extra seconds to the load-time, and my users are ok with that.

However, I'm also seeing a significant pause after the user clicks the button to save the data in the update panel.  I've proofed out that the lag-time only happens when there is a lot of data in the dropdown, and there doesn't seem to be any specific line of code that's responsible... just the presence of a large dropdown seems to bog things down at update-time.  I've tried turning off "EnableViewState" on the control with no impact.

Is this normal for large dropdowns and I'll just have to live with it and/or redesign? Or can anyone recommend a fix?  I find it weird that the delay at Update is actually LONGER than the original load-time delay, and my customer is being fairly resistant to a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Move your large DropDownList (and any other control that you don't need to rebuild on the asyncpostback) outside of the UpdatePanel.  When the UpdatePanel updates, it rebuilds all the html for the controls that are inside the `<ContentTemplate>`.  If you don't need to rebuild that dropdown it shouldn't be in there.  Depending on the page layout you may need to use multiple UpdatePanels.